# How do I download a whole website that is a "remote access" to a server?

Tags: linux, windows, download, website

I have a problem, how am i supposed to download a website that looks like a dropbox, it's a server remote access, that has folders containing folders and files etc. that i am interested in. I', stuck with that since like 3 hours and just nothing will work!

Can anyone help?! Please!

This is the website that i am trying to rip completely:

```
https://remoteaccess.tappin.com/access/d14c94d8-1a82-452f-a6b9-a41ff59aa3de/
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this should have been asked in the product's forum instead of here, but:

These cloud file server services usually offer a 'Desktop sync' app to download files.

https://tappin.com/tappin-desktop-agent

You'll need to install that and login to your account.